# Python 3: Issues setting secondary y axis labels with FuncFormatter

Tags: python, plot, ticker

I have created a figure that has two y axes that are sharing one x axis. The y axes are correlated to each other: the values of the left y-axis are an input to an equation that gives the values of the right y-axis. To correlate the two, I set the y ticks on each axis to be the same. Then I tried to use a function (myticks) to label the y ticks on each axis with the proper labels using set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myticks)). The y ticks are in the correct position on each axes and the labels are correct on the left axis, but the labels are incorrect on the right axis. For some reason, the left axis labels are showing up on the right axis as well. The values of the right axis should be the values present in right_y2. I'm brand new to Python, so any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

y =[1.9E19,1E20,5E20,1.8E21,1E22,1.9E22,1.15E23]
ax1.plot(2,y[0],marker='o')
ax1.plot(2,y[1],marker='o')
ax1.plot(2,y[2],marker='o')
ax1.plot(2,y[3],marker='o')
ax1.plot(2,y[4],marker='o')
ax1.plot(2,y[5],marker='o')
ax1.plot(2,y[6],marker='o')
ax1.set_yscale("log")
ax1.set_ylim(1E19,2E23)
ax1.set_yticks(y)

def myticks(left_y,y):
    exponent = int(np.log10(left_y))
    coeff = left_y/10**exponent
    return r"${:2.0f} \times 10^{{ {:2d} }}$".format(coeff,exponent)

ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myticks))

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_yscale("log")
ax2.set_ylim(1E19,2E23)
ax2.set_yticks(y)


def myticks2(right_y2,y):
    exponent2 = int(np.log10(right_y2))
    coeff2 = right_y2/10**exponent2
    return r"${:2.0f} \times 10^{{ {:2d} }}$".format(coeff2,exponent2)

ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myticks2)
```

where

```
left_y =[1.9E19,1E20,5E20,1.8E21,1E22,1.9E22,1.15E23]
right_y2 =[5.3E12,3.8E13,1.3E14,2.7E14,5E14,9.6E14,3E15]
```

I get the following figure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTvZE.png)